# Ant target generate empty suite xml file

Tags: ant, junit

I am using ant for my project and I have been trying to generate JUnit report using ant target. The problem I run in to is that at the end of the execution my TESTS-TestSuites.xml is empty. But all the other individual test xml files have data. And due to this my html reports are empty, in the sense results shows "0".

Here is my ant target

```
    <!-- JUnit Reporting -->
<target name="test-report" depends="build-all" description="Generate Test Results as HTML">

    <taskdef name="junitreport" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLResultAggregator"/>
    <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="off" haltonerror="off" fork="yes">
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${test.reports}" filtertrace="on">
            <fileset dir="${build.classes}" includes="**/Test*Selenium.class"/>
        </batchtest>
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
        <formatter type="xml" usefile="true"/>
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath"/>
            <path refid="application"/>
        </classpath>
    </junit>
    <echo message="running JUnit Report" />
    <junitreport todir="${test.reports}">
        <fileset dir="${test.reports}">
            <include name="Test-*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${test.reports.html}" />
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

This is what I get as ant print summary,

```
[junitreport] Processing C:\YukonSelenium\reports\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to   C:\DOCUME~1\user\LOCALS~1\Temp\null1848051184

[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/C:/DevApps/apache-ant-1.7.1/lib/ant
junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] Transform time: 859ms
[junitreport] Deleting: C:\DOCUME~1\user\LOCALS~1\Temp\null1848051184
```

Here's how junit report looks like
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?43dd69d3b8.jpg

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

I think its issue related to case. You have said that Test-*.xml. I think It should be TEST-*.xml

That's why its not aggregating results. For more information give ant option as -v. u can see what all files report target picked up.